# Web app on azure doesn't show my asp.net core web app after I have published it without any problems

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

[Landing Page of my web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBLPn.jpg)

I have published my asp.net core mvc project in the Azure as web app, however it doesn't show anything. Instead of this it just shows the landing page as there was no code (which is not the case). I have checked few points on stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything, could anyone please help me with that?

Comment: @JoeyCai the below steps didn't change anything unfortunately, however I have just deleted the app service and re-published it again. I still don't have the "Default documents" in the Configuration, but the app is working now. I didn't do only the last step, which is publishing the app from github, is this "Default documents" shows up only if you publish it from git or it should show up in any case?

Comment: I have update my reply and you could accept it as answer to help others who has same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few reasons causing it, you could refer to the following and troubleshoot it.

1. Go to your kudu site to check whether all your project file have uploaded to azure.
2. After publishing webapp to azure, wait for a moment.
3. Make sure you default page is listed in here and is above hostingstart.html

[image]

4. [Deploy Continuous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) to Azure App Service.

Update:

5. Delete app and republish it.